# Synchronous SubmissionPublisher

Tags: java, reactive, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, java-flow

Is it possible to make Subscriber run on the same thread as the Publisher (synchronously)?
I can use CompletableFuture, but it delivers only a single result. But what if I need many results delivered to the subscriber. Please look at this small tests for a better explanation.

```
  @Test
  public void testCompletableFutureThreads() throws InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<String> f = new CompletableFuture<String>();
    f.thenAccept(new Consumer<String>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(String s) {
        System.out.println("accept " + s + " in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
    });
    Thread.sleep(200);
    System.out.println("send complete from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    f.complete("test");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }



  @Test
  public void testSubmissionPublisherThreads() throws InterruptedException {

    SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<String>();

    publisher.subscribe(new Flow.Subscriber<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
        subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(String item) {
        System.out.println("onNext in " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " received " + item);
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        System.err.println("onError in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        throwable.printStackTrace(System.err);
      }

      @Override
      public void onComplete() {
        System.err.println("onComplete in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
    });

    int i = 10;
    while (i-- > 0) {
      Thread.sleep(100);
      System.out.println("publisher from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      publisher.submit("" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
  }
```

Comment: do you have a single subscriber and a single publisher or there can be either many subscribers and/or publishers?

Comment: single publisher and many subscribers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`SubmissionPublisher(Executor, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.concurrent.Executor,int)) constructor and provide an `Executor` that runs everything on the current thread:

```java
final SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>(new Executor() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        command.run();
    }
}, Flow.defaultBufferSize());
```

or, if you prefer lambdas:

```java
final SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>(Runnable::run, Flow.defaultBufferSize());
```

The default constructor uses `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` to send signals.